# Can't use Slick-Slider with Dynamic data whwn pulling from external API

Tags: vuejs2, slick.js

Trying to build a website with some sliders.for slider i used SLICK slider.Here is my code .

```js
<template>
    <div class="homePopularVenue">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="text-center sub-headwords">POPULAR VENUE</h2>
            <!--slider start-->
            <div class="home-slider-popular-venue">
                
                <div>
                    <div class="well">
                        <span class="half-image-temp">
                            <img class="img-rsponsive" src=" http://placehold.it/250x150" alt="">
                        </span>
                        <span class="half-content-temp">
                            <h3 class="title">HELLOW</h3>
                            <h5 class="small">Welcome to Hellow World</h5>
                           
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default btn-small">BOOK NOW</a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                
                
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-center btn btn-primary">VIEW ALL</a>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'homePopularVenue',
  data () {
    return {
      posts: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.create();
    this.$http.get('https://newsapi.org/v1/sources?language=en')
      .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
          this.posts = response.data.source;
          
      })
  },
  methods:{
    create (){
      $('.home-slider-popular-venue').slick({
          slidesToShow: 4,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          infinite: true,
          dots: true,
          autoplay: true,
          autoplaySpeed: 2000,
          responsive: [
                {
                breakpoint: 1024,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 3,
                    slidesToScroll: 3,
                    infinite: true,
                    dots: true
                }
                },
                {
                breakpoint: 600,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 2
                }
                },
                {
                breakpoint: 480,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                }
                }
            ]
        });
        
    }
  },
  created: function(){
      
  }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
.sub-headwords:after{
    content:"";
    width:200px;
    background: #F99A13;
    height: 4px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.home-slider-popular-venue .well{
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 8px 0 rgba(46,61,73,.2); 
    margin: 30px 10px; 
    transition: .2s ease-in-out; 
}
.home-slider-popular-venue .well:hover{
    box-shadow: 12px 15px 20px 0 rgba(46,61,73,.15); 
}

.half-image-temp{
    max-height: 250px;
}
.half-image-temp img{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
.half-content-temp{

}


</style>
```

Everything was good before i put the data dynamicaly in slider, after putting the data dynamically in slider its not working.

```js
<template>
    <div class="homePopularVenue">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="text-center sub-headwords">POPULAR VENUE</h2>
            <!--slider start-->
            <div class="home-slider-popular-venue">
                
                <div v-for="post in posts">
                    <div class="well">
                        <span class="half-image-temp">
                            <img class="img-rsponsive" src=" http://placehold.it/250x150" alt="">
                        </span>
                        <span class="half-content-temp">
                            <h3 class="title">HELLOW</h3>
                            <h5 class="small">Welcome to Hellow World</h5>
                           <p> {{post.id}} </p>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default btn-small">BOOK NOW</a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                
                
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-center btn btn-primary">VIEW ALL</a>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
</template>
```

Also the same problem is happening with OWl.Carousel.

Comment: `{{post.id}}` in not defined anywhere. I guess you forgot to set up `v-for="post in posts"` or something like this.

Comment: I expect you want to initialize `slick` whenever the data is updated. Here, you initialize it in `created` which is *before* the data is returned. You might want to do it in `.then` *after* `this.posts` is set.

Comment: I have defined v-for="post in post" to the parent element of the slider ,u can see it in second code pallet that i have defined.

Comment: Bert Evans i use your idea too but still not good.slider is working properly for a second, after the data is initialized and {{post.id}} got its value, the slider stop working

Comment: If you put together a fiddle demonstrating the issue I can help you.

Comment: again i put your advice in my component nd this thime i got success.